# Como separar uma string passando mais de um parâmetro

Tags: python, string

Tenho o seguinte arquivo de texto, salvo como `texto.txt`:

```
Vamos testar nesse arquivo, aqui.  
Temos que pedir para, que separe "todos os caracteres"!  
Fazer, a contagem de letras?  
Fazer a contagem de cada letra, que aparece aqui.  
Fazer a contagem de linhas.  
Esse texto contem 6 linhas.
```

O texto tem vários símbolos justamente para testar a separação da string.

Elaborei o seguinte código para ler o arquivo:

```
with open('texto.txt', encoding='utf8') as arquivo:
    letras = arquivo.read()
    lista = letras.split(' ') 
    print(lista)
```

O `read()` lê todo o arquivo e salva como uma string em letras.
Acontece que ao pedir para exibir letras, a resposta dada é:

```
['Temos', 'que', 'pedir', 'para,', 'que', 'separe', '"todos', 'os', 'caracteres"!\nFazer,', 'a','contagem', 'de', 'letras?\nFazer', 'a', 'contagem', 'de', 'cada', 'letra,', 'que', 'aparece','aqui.\nFazer', 'a', 'contagem', 'de', 'linhas.\nEsse', 'texto', 'contem', '6', 'linhas.']
```

Note que só é separado onde tem espaço vazio.
Como faço para que ele separe também quando encontar `,.!?`, espaços vazios e quando encontrar também o `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Para solucionar seu problema vamos utilizar alguns recursos do próprio python, a biblioteca nativa re, funções e laços, tudo isso para que resolvamos o problema seguindo um design pattern.

o código ficou assim:

```
import os
import re

def lerArquivo(caminho):
    with open(caminho, encoding='utf8') as arquivo:
        dictionaryInput = arquivo.read() 
        return dictionaryInput

def separar(lista):
    splitResult = re.split('([^a-zA-Z0-9])', lista)
    finalListResult = []
    for x in splitResult:
        if x != '\n' and x != '' and x != ' ':
            finalListResult.append(x)
    return finalListResult


caminho = r'.\texto.txt'
lerCaminho = lerArquivo(caminho)
print(separar(lerCaminho))
```

Qualquer dúvida que restar a cerca do código e suas funções é só perguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Se não houver necessidade de preservar estes caracteres/ sequências "especiais", você pode apenas fazer um `replace` de todas estas sequências conhecidas por um espaço vazio. Desta forma, apenas o `split(' ')` será suficiente para quebrar o texto conforme desejado.